# Integer function that loops over a range

Tags: functions

I've been trying to figure out how I'd write such a non-piecewise linear function that given input x outputs only numbers from the range -180 to 180 by 'looping' over them. Meaning, in the range -180 and 180, $x = f(x)$, then above 180, for example $x = 181$, $f(x) = -179$. It 'looped' back to the beginning of that range when stepping over the boundary of it. Same behavior the opposite way.. for $x = -181$, $f(x) = 179$, etc.

I've made some attempts but the best I was able to come up with was

$$f(x) = mod(x, sign(x)*180)$$

which is nearly but not quite right, as under -180 it just loops between 0 and -180 instead of the full range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \mathop{\rm sign}(x) \Big[ \big\{ (|x|+179)\mod 360\big\} - 179 \Big]$ should do the trick.

Comment: That is it!.. How'd you figure it out so quickly?.. Just experience?

Comment: In large part, yes. Thinking of just positive integers, the sequence of values repeats with period $360$, so that suggests the "mod $360$" part. The other constants were sort of trial and error (paying attention to the desired values at 180 and 181). Using sign$(x)$ (and thus $|x|$) to let the negative inputs ride the coattails of the positive inputs was your idea!

Answer (score 0):

So I thought about this a little and came up with a general equation to achieve this effect for any range of values! Hope this is useful to someone

$$f(x) = \mathop{\rm sign}(x) \Big[ \big\{ (|x|+\frac{b-a}{2})\mod (b-a)\big\} - \frac{b-a}{2} \Big] + \frac{b+a}{2}$$

Where $a$ is the minimum value and $b$ is the maximum value. For instance if $a=25$ and $b=150$ then it will loop between 25 and 125